# Cannot call instance method from static method

Tags: java

I have this class and I just need help with the `toString()` inside the methods to actually show the result. It gives me an error that I can't use `getName()` or `getId()` in a static context :

```
public static void bubbleSort(Student[] array)
{
    for(int i=(array.length); i>0; i--)
        for(int j=1; j<(array.length-i); j++)
            if(array[j].getName().compareTo(
               array[j+1].getName())<0) {
                Student Temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = Temp;
            }

    String s = null;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    // the error is here under the getName and getId 
        s= s+ getName()+" "+ getId() ;
    } 
    System.out.print (s);
}
```

Comment: Make `getName` and `getId` static too. **or** make `bubbleSort` not static.

Comment: Initialize s with "" instead of null and write s = s + array[i].getName()+" "+ array[i].getId()

Comment: i need the bubblesort method to be static because im using a test class this class is just for the methods and constructor

Comment: Seems like you are using both the correct way and wrong way in the same code..

Comment: A `static` method works the exact same on every instane of the class. A `non-static` method is a method that is applied to a certain instance of a class, an `object`. Obviously, you want to call the `getName` and `getId` on a certain instance of a class, as (even if they were possible to call without an object) they would have no effect or impact on the general class. I believe you are a bit confused on object-oriented programming and such stuff, maybe you can take some time studying this.

Comment: @NidoAlSaher: It sounds like you really need to read up about what it means for a method to be static, and the implications. If the method needs state from an instance (ID and name), it either needs to be an instance method, or it needs to be given a reference to an instance. *Which object* did you expect it to get the name from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to print the names and IDs of the `Student`s you previously sorted.

```
public static void bubbleSort(Student[] array)
{
    for(int i=(array.length); i>0; i--)
    {

        for(int j=1; j<(array.length-i); j++) 
        {
             if( array[j].getName().compareTo(array[j+1].getName())<0)

            {
                Student Temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = Temp;
            }

        }
    }

    String s = ""; // should not be null

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        s = s + array[i].getName()+" "+ array[i].getId(); // changed this line
        System.out.print (s); // moved this into the loop because I think this makes more sense
    }
}
```

The methods `getName()` and `getID()` belong to the object `Student` and are not methods of the class where `bubbleSort()` is defined.

Comment: `for (Student s: array) System.out.println(s.getName()+' '+s.getId());`

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
s= s+ getName()+" "+ getId() ;
```

you probably need to do this:

```
s= s+ array[i].getName()+" "+ array[i].getId() ;
```

and as said in the comment above use:

```
String s = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `array[i].getName()` and `array[i].getId()` instead of just `getName()` and `getId()`.