# Bubble sort strings in descending order

Tags: java, sorting

I have to sort a string of names in descending order in bubble sort.  I tried but it is not working. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void bubbleSort(Student[] array)
{
    for(int i=(array.length); i>0; i--)
    {    
        for(int j=1; j<(array.length-i); j++) 
        {
            if( array[j].getName().compareTo(array[j+1].getName())<0)    
            {
                Student Temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = Temp;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We will not solve all your [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988751/cannot-call-instance-method-from-static-method) ;)

Comment: How, specifically, is it not working? What are you getting as output vs. what you're expecting to get? In general, we prefer specific questions here, but at the very least, be as specific as possible about what you don't understand.

Comment: since it's homework, you should do it yourself. that means learning how to do debugging... put in some debug output to specify the array indexes and values you're working on, then step through the program and see what's happening.

Comment: in the first for lopp make i >= 0 and in the second for lopp initialize j = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this logic

```
   import java.util.*;

    public class BubbleSort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String l[]={"ABCD" , "XYZ" , "DEF" , "PQR"};
    BubbleSort(l);
    for(int i=0; i<l.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(l[i]);
    }
  }

 private static void BubbleSort(String[] array) {
    String t;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<array.length-1-i; j++) {
        if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1])>0) {
            t= array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = t;
        }
    }
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: This will not work because the question is about comparing names, not numbers.

Comment: why do i get an error by the t variable last line i tried converting t type to student but it still won't work

Comment: @RahulTripathi  why do i get an error by the t variable last line i tried converting t type to student but it still won't work

Comment: type mismatch cannot convert from String to Student @RahulTripathi

Comment: if i do that i get an error in this line                         Student t= array[j].getName();    // the error is under the array[j].getName() it says cannot convert from string to student   @RahulTripathi

Comment: Try again, I have updated my answer(Infact now its the full program). Hope this resolves your problem and if it resolves your purpose then do accept it and an upvote(if possible) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm eight years and a month late, but for anyone with the same problem now, here's the solution code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scnr=new Scanner(System.in);
        String arr[]= new String[20];
        
        System.out.println("Enter names:");
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            arr[i]= scnr.nextLine();
        }
        
        String temp; int i;
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            for(i=j+1; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
                //comparing adjacent string
                if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) > 0)
                {
                    temp=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```