# How to BubbleSort an array in descending order?

Tags: c#, sorting, bubble-sort, descendant

```
private static double[] BubbleSortAscending(double[] numberArray)
{
    int arrayLength = numberArray.Length;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < arrayLength - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if(numberArray[j] > numberArray[j + 1])
            {
                double num = numberArray[j];
                numberArray[j] = numberArray[j + 1];
                numberArray[j + 1] = num;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberArray;
}
```

Hello, in the code above I have managed to make it so that it sorts an array in *ascending* order, however I am fully stuck and stumped on how to *edit* or *change* it to make it sort in *descending* order? Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Reverse condition: `if(numberArray[j] < numberArray[j + 1])`

Comment: not the most efficient solution: simply reverse your array at end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bubble sort strings in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988900/bubble-sort-strings-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do if you want to *reverse* sorting (in *descending* instead of *ascemding* order) is to *reverse* the condition: `<` instead of `>`:

```
   ...
   if(numberArray[j] < numberArray[j + 1])
   ...
```